# Good automated system testing framework in python

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, system-testing

I am looking for good End to End testing framework under python, where the tests can be written in python and managed in a comfortable way. I know there are many unit testing frameworks, but I am looking for bigger scope, something like test director with support for reports etc,where a whole system is under test.

Comment: What is the front end? How about the back end?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You havent given any details so it is very difficult to know what specific product are you looking for. 
Maybe [robotframework](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework) suits your needs

Comment: Interesting. Have you actually used it ? Any knowledge about it ?

Comment: Yes I am building something similar for test automation so I was having a look at the application

Comment: The nicest thing about robotframework is that it can be used for a multitude of things, whether it is for UI tests, functional back-end tests, or just to perform some simple repeatable function or set of functions!  Just be careful to choose the keywords carefully otherwise things can get out of hand.  We've all seen what happens when we try meshing english into a programming language (e.g. visual basic)...there are ways to discriminate when duplicate keywords are present across multiple libraries but even then it's a good idea to choose keywords wisely and spend that time upfront.

Answer (score 0):

I used zope.testing and it was very good for my need, but it's not so different from simple unittest.

There is a good comparative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826734/good-automated-system-testing-framework-in-python). I guess most of the products cited are more of the unit testing kind. Not sure you will find what you look for.

Comment: Your link is wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The TTCN3 is a quite good test framework for black-box testing. The comercial tools are having lot of reporting stuff there. It is not in python.